# Launching shell command through python

Tags: python-3.x, os.system

I am trying to execute a command shell for a list of files so i tried this code

```
import glob
import shutil
import os


def recursListPath(path, nth = 1):
list = []
for i in range (1, nth+1):
    currentpath = path + (i * "/*")
    for name in glob.glob(currentpath):
        list.append(name)
return list

version = "SPIRIT/1685-2009"
DirPath = "D:\\all-data"
list = recursListPath(DirPath, 4)
for item in list:
   if os.path.isfile(item):
      fichier=open(item, encoding="mbcs")
      for ligne in fichier :
        if version in ligne:
           print("'%s' 2009" % fichier.name)
           os.system("'%s' start C:\> script.sh -file textVersionChange.tcl -w wk -log convertversion.log -args" %fichier.name "converteddir" )
      fichier.close()
```

The console is launched for each file but nothing is generated
how to use a variable in themiddle of a command with os.system ?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an `os.system` issue. 
I will preface this by saying I don't work on windows and I'm assuming that your actual commandline is correct? (The `C:\>` looks kind of odd to me)

I have to say I'm not actually sure how this: 
`"'%s' start C:\> script.sh -file textVersionChange.tcl -w wk -log convertversion.log -args" %fichier.name "converteddir"` isn't returning a syntax error.

I'm not sure exactly what you want that command to look like but you could change the string formatting to start with.

Try:

`"'{name}' start C:\> script.sh -file textVersionChange.tcl -w wk -log convertversion.log -args converteddir".format(name=fichier.name)`

Also, I would consider using the newer [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) instead of `os.system`.

You could then provide your commandline as a list:

`[fichier.name, "start", "C:\> script.sh", "-file", "textVersionChange.tcl", "-w", "wk", "-log", "convertversion.log", "-args", fichier.name, "converteddir"]`

which can include variables.